# How to make user elegible for FB push campaign in phonegap app?

Tags: facebook, push-notification, phonegap

I am using this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-push-campaign

Also followed the instructions in this link. I have added this line:

```
 cordova.plugins.FacebookPushCampaign.register(pushToken);
```

But it seems that this is not reflecting in my FB analytics. When I tried creating push campaign, and sent a push notification it results to 0 notifications delivered.I manually send a notif on my phone and it works. So maybe the plugin is not registering the token toFB correctly?

Have anyone tried this plugin before?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a day of debugging. I followed again what is stated in the plugin's documentation and it seems working fine now. What happened is that I was confused about the comment in the documentation.

```
// grab the token and pass it to Facebook
cordova.plugins.FacebookPushCampaign.register(pushToken);
```

So what I did was (which is INCORRECT):

```
cordova.plugins.FacebookPushCampaign.register(pushToken.registrationId); //I passed the device token itself
```

But I realized that the FB analytics accepts the whole response of the registration event (CORRECT):

```
pushPlugin
.init({
  ios: {
    badge:      'true',
    sound:      'true',
    alert:      'true',
    clearBadge: 'true',
  }
})
// wait for the plugin to register the Push Token 
.on('registration', function(pushToken) {
  // grab the token and pass it to Facebook
  //pushToken looks like {'registrationId':xxxxx}
  cordova.plugins.FacebookPushCampaign.register(pushToken); //Yes, pass the response of the registration event
});
```

LESSON: Read the documentation. If the documentation is confusing, test it and see if you misunderstood something (like what happened to me).